# How to put elements centered within an image caption?

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image with an image caption that has text and another smaller image inside it. Currently they are mushed together and I want them separate. I tried putting an inner div for the text and a separate one for the image but it doesn't work and breaks the image caption (makes two image captions overlapping each other). How to put elements centered within an image caption?

```css
#gallery-img {
  position: relative;
}
#caption div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-img">
  <img src="http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/10/4a206b7a-8ee2.jpg" alt="demo">
  <h2 id="caption"><div><b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br/><a href="#">See more</a><img style="width:10%;" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png"></div></h2>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve this look:

[image]

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to use the map tag and one image. Why? What if the browser doesn't have the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this!

```css
#gallery-img img {
  float:right;
  width:7%;
}
#gallery-img {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-img">
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png">
  <div id="caption"><b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br/><a href="#">See more</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the image inside of `h2`:

```css
#gallery-img {
  position: relative;
}
#caption div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#caption img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-img">
  <img src="http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/10/4a206b7a-8ee2.jpg" alt="demo">
  <h2 id="caption"><div><b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br/><a href="#">See more</a><img style="width:10%;" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png"></div></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

assign `float: left;` (or `display: inline-block;`) to the `#gallery-img` container  to contain that container to the size of the image inside. Assign `display: block;` to the `img` so it doesn't use additional white space to create layout on the page, then use `right: 0;` instead of `width: 100%;` on the `#caption div` so it doesn't push beyond the bounds of `#gallery-img` due to the box-model. Also, absolutely position `#caption` so that it's margins are taken into consideration in the positioning, instead of absolutely positioning the `div` inside of `#caption`. Is this what you're going for?

```css
#gallery-img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#gallery-img img {
  display: block;
  }
#caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-img">
  <img src="http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/10/4a206b7a-8ee2.jpg" alt="demo">
  <h2 id="caption"><div><b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br/><a href="#">See more</a><img style="width:10%;" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png"></div></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption><b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br><a href="#">See more</a></figcaption>
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the main image as a background image? This would simplify the code considerably.
You could then place the copy and secondary image in separate div's and float them left and right inside of another container with margin set to 0 auto in order to center. Sample code below.

```css
#gallery-img {
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/10/4a206b7a-8ee2.jpg');
  width:640px;
  height:640px;
}
#caption {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding:15px 0;
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
}
#container {
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#copy {
  float:left;
  width:340px;
}

#image-container {
  float:right;
  width:40px;
}

h2 { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<div id="gallery-img">
    <div id="caption">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="copy">
          <h2>
          <b>Stats:</b> Advanced Mathematics<br/>
          <a href="#">See more</a>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="image-container">
          <img style="width:100%;" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clipart-pink-circle-clip-art-at-vector-clip-art-2.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```